# How to create a wrapper that rewrites all the arguments in some cases?

Tags: shell-script

I want to make a wrapper around FFMPEG, because changing my application isn't easy and also because I want to act only in specific commands.

By default, I want to forward all the command, but always changing `-loglevel warning` to `error`

And if my wrapper receives a command with the string "id=2015" or "id=2016" or "id=2017" I want to forward ONLY my arguments to ffmpeg.

How can I do this?

example:

```
ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel warning -err_detect ignore_err -fflags +genpts -async 1 -probesize 5000000 -analyzeduration 5000000 -progress http://127.0.0.1:80/progress.php?stream_id=2015 -i http://link -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec copy -map 0 -copy_unknown -individual_header_trailer 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 3 -segment_format_options mpegts_flags=+initial_discontinuity:mpegts_copyts=1 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live+delete -segment_list /var/html/www/2015_.m3u8 /var/html/www/2015_%d.ts
```

This command contains the id=2015, so if that happens I want to instead call ffmpeg with:

```
ffmpeg $mycommands
```

Nothing from the original command will be passed IF the original command contains id=2015|2014|etc

Comment: This looks like a perfect use case for regular expressions.

Comment: I'm trying this but it doesn't work for me... ```command="$@" ``` then I try ```echo ${command/warning/error}"``` but i get a bad substitution error

Comment: Are you running this as Bash or sh which can be dash, ash, mksh or something else?

Comment: I'm running as bash. However I managed to make it work now with awk. ```command=$(echo $@ | awk '{gsub("warning","error"); print}')``` this always replaces ```warning``` with ```error```. Now I Just need to find if the command contain a list of IDs, so I can forward a different command, and if it doesn't just pass the command as usual

Comment: What if your command call does not contain `-loglevel`, do you want to add it ?

Comment: My software always call ffmpeg with the same arguments

Comment: @Freedo: _I'm running as bash._, well it doesn't look like, it would work if you ran it with Bash. Run `bash <script>` and check if it works.

Comment: oh my bad it seems it wasn't using bash... but my issue to check if the original commands  is using one of the IDs i want to watch for to change the command persists

Answer (score 2):

I don't think simple replacement is a good idea, maybe your file has `warning` as part of its name?

I'd rather loop the arguments and replace it when `-loglevel` found:

```bsh
ffmpeg(){
  args=()
  while (( $# )); do
    args=("${args[@]}" "$1")
    if [ "$1" = "-loglevel" ]; then
      args=("${args[@]}" "error")
      shift
    fi
    shift
  done
  /usr/bin/ffmpeg "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Was that part of your original question? If so, please edit your question and add details, maybe an example command call.

Comment: edit your question, thank you.

Comment: no, please provide an example command

Comment: check now. I think I'm clear now

Comment: I'm looking for something like this ```[[ $command =~ ^(id=2015|id=2020)$ ]] && echo "this command will be rewritten"``` but this always says it will be rewritten